# java regex to match multiple new line characters up to character

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text string, consisting of a block of text followed by two or more 
new line characters (\n maybe \r) followed by another block of text,etc like this

*multiple line text*

*(two or more new line characters)*

*multiple line tex*

*(two or more new line characters)*

I would like to break this string into as many substrings as the number of blocks of text using the new lines as the breaking boundary.

I tried

```
public static int indexOf(Pattern pattern, String s) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
    }


pStart[i-1] = start + indexOf(Pattern.compile("[\\n\\n]+"), text.substring(start));
```

but it doesnt work.

Is there a better idea to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any easy way is to use the String Split Function with a Regex:

```
String sampleText = new String("first\nsecond\n\r");
String [] blocks = sampleText.split("\n{1,}[\r]?");
```

The above assumes '1 or more \n' and optionally '1 \r'.
You can change the regex to '\n{2,}[\r]?' for two or more '\n' depending on what you want.

[Oracle Java 6 String Split Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that `[\\n\\n]` means only one new line character `\n` since it is inside character class. Inside character class only one of the listed characters are matched.

You can use:

```
\\n{2}
```

instead to match new newline characters.